# Split one array in two arrays with react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I would like to split an array into two arrays (one for letters and the other for frequencies).

```
var list = [ "ES 324798", "LE 237076", "EN 231193" ]
```

This is the array that I want to split.

I would like to get an array with all letters like this :

```
var letters = [ "ES", "LE", "EN" ]
```

And an other with numbers :

```
var numbers = [ "324798", "237076", "231193" ]
```

I searched for "how to split one array in two arrays with React native" but I don't find what I want. I tried with split and splice functions but it didn't help me (or I just don't know how to use them properly).

Can you give me some tips ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution could be using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Try the following:

```js
const list = [ "ES 324798", "LE 237076", "EN 231193" ];

const result = list.reduce((a, c) => {
  const split = c.split(' ');
  a.letters.push(split[0]);
  a.numbers.push(split[1]);
  return a;
}, { letters: [], numbers: [] });

const { letters, numbers } = result;

console.log('letters', letters);
console.log('numbers', numbers);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Why my first element "ES" isn't in the both arrays ?

`getBigrams = () => {
    List.reduce((a, c) => {
      const split = c.split(' ');
      this.state.BigramsLetters.push(split[0]);
      this.state.BigramsFrequency.push(parseInt(split[1], 10));
      return a;
    })
    console.log('letters', this.state.BigramsLetters);
    console.log('numbers', this.state.BigramsFrequency);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

This is not about React Native.

I would do:

```
const letters = []
const numbers = []
list.forEach((item) => {
  const [ letter, number ] = item.split(' ')
  letters.push(letter)
  numbers.push(number)
})
```